# Implementation of Node.JS Certificate check differs on platforms

Tags: node.js

it seems to me the implementation of the Certificate check in Node.JS differs on platforms like Linux or Windows. And in cases it works on Linux it doesn't on windows sometime.

Comment: this is as of node version v0.10.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wanted to share this, since i kind of fell over it.

At my workplace we have a few test servers running an work-in-progress API. When querying them with Node i discovered some significant  implementation mismatches, when either running on Windows or Linux.

The server has a self signed certificate for HTTPS request and when querying with https.request(....); on Linux there is no problem at all.

When i try this on windows, i get certificate errors. Which made me look for solutions. All i could find was some help on using the global agent and use `SSLv3_method`. Didn't work either in this case.

Per coincidence i found how to disable certificate checking in node, by setting these request options:
`rejectUnauthorized: false,
requestCert: true,
agent: false`

I hope this is helpful for someone when finding this via google.

Feel free to start a discussion or prove me wrong on this. Some other colleagues and me went through this and this cost me nearly a day to figure out.